# Unrecognised schema error

Tags: reactjs, meteor, simple-schema

Did you try adding ?

'name': {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    uniforms: TextField
  }

I'm getting an error while trying to implement `vazco/uniforms` with simpleschema. The error message is, `Invariant Violation: Unrecognised schema: [object Object]`. I'm not sure what this package is asking for.

Path: `Schema`

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
import TextField from 'uniforms-bootstrap3/AutoForm'; // Choose your theme package.

export const ProfileCandidate = new Mongo.Collection('profileCandidate');

const ProfileCandidateSchema = new SimpleSchema({
  'name.first': {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    uniforms: TextField
  }
});

ProfileCandidate.attachSchema(ProfileCandidateSchema);
```

Path: `Form`

```
import AutoForm from 'uniforms-bootstrap3/AutoForm';
import ProfileCandidateSchema from '../../../../api/profileCandidate/profileCandidate';

export default class CareerHistoryFormPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(doc) {
    console.log("Doc: ", doc);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="paper">
        <AutoForm schema={ProfileCandidateSchema} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran across this same problem then realized that the `ProfileCanidate` schema needs a prop of `schema` on your original simple schema, it can't be separately named `ProfileCanidateSchema` (which is the syntax I usually use as well). So to edit your code, things should look more along the lines of this:

```
import { Mongo } from 'meteor/mongo';
import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';
import TextField from 'uniforms-bootstrap3/AutoForm'; // Choose your theme 
package.

export const ProfileCandidate = new Mongo.Collection('profileCandidate');

ProfileCandidate.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  'name.first': {
    type: String,
    optional: true,
    uniforms: TextField
  }
});

ProfileCandidate.attachSchema(ProfileCandidate.schema);
```

and

```
import AutoForm from 'uniforms-bootstrap3/AutoForm';
import ProfileCandidate from 
'../../../../api/profileCandidate/profileCandidate';

export default class CareerHistoryFormPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super(...arguments);

    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  handleSubmit(doc) {
    console.log("Doc: ", doc);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="paper">
        <AutoForm schema={ProfileCandidate.schema} onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This should get rid of the `Invariant Violation: Unrecognised schema: [object Object]` error for you.